# IPYTHON Script that takes an arbitrary number of input files, strips + stores the header, and saves data points

Tags: matplotlib, ipython

I am trying to take any number of files (1-10 for simplicity?) that are specified on the command line, strip + store the headers, and saves data points (Then later plots it using MATPLOT. The last command line specified name will be the name of an output file.

What I have below is a script that takes 2 command line specified files and plots them, with the 3rd command line name specifying the name of the output file.

```
import sys
sys.argv
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.legend_handler import HandlerLine2D
import numpy as np

# Reads Arguments
ReadFile1 = sys.argv[1]
ReadFile2 = sys.argv[2]
WriteFile = sys.argv[3]


# opens file
RedFile1 = open(ReadFile1)
RedFile2 = open(ReadFile2)


###
### Start collecting data ###
###


# Removes header from file 1 and stores it
header1 = RedFile1.readline().rstrip()

# Creates a list from values in file 1 , reads argument specified file,
# puts data into the list, and converts into an array.
Data1 = []

for line in RedFile1:
     Data1.append(line.rstrip().split(','))
Reference1 = np.array(Data1).astype(np.float)

# Seperates array into x and y values in the first document
# based on the columb it is in
xvalues1 = Reference1[:, 0]
yvalues1 = Reference1[:, 1]


######
###### moving on to the second part ######
######


# Removes header from file 2, stores it, and puts it in an array.
header2 = RedFile2.readline().rstrip()

# Creates a list from values in file 2 , reads argument specified file,
# puts data into the list, and converts into an array.
Data2 = []

for line in RedFile2:
    Data2.append(line.rstrip().split(','))
Reference2 = np.array(Data2).astype(np.float)

# Seperates array into x and y values in the second document
# based on the columb it is in
xvalues2 = Reference2[:,0]
yvalues2 = Reference2[:,1]


######
###### Graphing ######
######


# Spits out a graph of file 1 and 2 together
line1 = plt.plot(xvalues1, yvalues1, 'o-', label = header1)
line2 = plt.plot(xvalues2, yvalues2, 'o-', label = header2)
plt.ylabel('Cell Count')
plt.xlabel('Time (min)')

plt.legend(numpoints=1, loc=0)


# Saves the graph into the argument specified name
plt.savefig(WriteFile)
```

My pathetic attempt looks like:

```
import sys
sys.argv
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Takes arguments, places them in list rawr, then the for loop opens each file, strips
# the header,  and places the headers into allheaders
rawr = sys.argv[1:-1]

#Write file name
WriteFile = sys.argv[-1]

#Opens a file, removes header and stores it, stores data in an array
#The array is accessed to create a list of x adn y values
#plot is constructed for one file
#loop continues until no more files


for n in rawr:
    open(n)
    header = n.readline().rstrip()

    Data = []
    for line in n:
        Data.append(line.rstrip().split(','))
    Reference1 = np.array(Data1).astype(np.float)

    xvalues = Reference[:, 0]
    yvalues = Reference[:, 1]

    plt.plot(xvalues, yvalues, label=header)


# Spits out a graph of file(s) together
plt.ylabel('Cell count')
plt.xlabel('Time min')
plt.legend(numpoints=1, loc=0)


# Saves the graph into the argument specified name
plt.savefig(WriteFile + '.png')
```

**EDIT**: I figured it out, here is the answer, the for loop should look like:

```
for n in rawr:
    eachfile = open(n)
    header = eachfile.readline().rstrip()

    Data = []
    for line in eachfile:
        Data.append(line.rstrip().split(','))
    Reference = np.array(Data).astype(np.float)

    xvalues = Reference[:, 0]
    yvalues = Reference[:, 1]

    line = plt.plot(xvalues, yvalues, 'o-', label=header)
```

Comment: Can you explain the problem with your attempt?  Are you getting an error?

Comment: I actually got the code to work! I just had to assign the opened file to a variable and do work on that variable:

Comment: Could you help me with something related to this?

Comment: I am trying to modify my script so that each input file may have an arbitrary (but fixed) number of columns (representing different replicates of the same experiment) and have the code plot the mean of the collection of replicates. What I added was:

Comment: yvals = []
    for row in Reference:
        yvals.append(np.mean(Reference[:, 1:]))
        yvalues = np.array(yvals).astype(np.float)
    print (yvalues)

Comment: This printed out 3 arrays, each that repeats a single number a number of times, instead of creating one array with an average of each row.

Comment: Glad you figured it out! It's probably best to post your new problem as a new question.